# How do you install openssl1.0 in a github action CI workflow on ubuntu-latest/18.04?

Tags: github-actions

I tried adding the following to the github steps in the yaml file from https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1307#issuecomment-664989873

```
steps:
    - name: Install openssl&libssl-dev
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades openssl=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.16 libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.16
    - name: Display openssl&libssl-dev versions
      run: dpkg -l openssl libssl-dev | grep '^ii' | cut -c5-
```

But received error `Version '1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.16' for 'openssl' was not found`

How do I figure out what "old versions" of openssl I can install in at least ubuntu 18.04 for github actions?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue.